# How can I disable automatically following redirects using python's httplib2?

Tags: python, httplib, httplib2

I would like to disable httplib2 from following redirects when I make a GET request to some site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable redirects on your `Http` object:

```
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()
http.follow_redirects = False
```